# Incorrect autocomplete with Javascript using nvim-lspconfig

Tags: neovim, filetype-javascript, lsp

My `lspconfig` works fine with typescript files, but not with Javascript.

- Autocomplete shows `.constructor` and other standard props/methods instead of the expected ones defined on the type
  [image]
- This happens even though the correct type is set (through jsdoc) or inferred from imported typescript modules
  [image]
- If I simply set the filetype to typescript (`:set ft=typescript`), it starts working
  [image]

I used the `Array` class in the example, but the issue is the same with user-defined types, even when the type definition is written using jsdoc.

How can I make autocomplete work as expected with Javascript files too?

Note: I use native LSP only, other plugins like `nvim-cmp` and `coq-nvim` work as expected, but I prefer to avoid them. Since they all use LSP, I suppose I am misconfiguring something.

My relevant configs:

`init.vim`

```
" LSP config
set omnifunc=v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc
set tagfunc=v:lua.vim.lsp.tagfunc

" open LSP definition
map <F9> :lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
inoremap <F9> <C-o>:lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>

" go to definition
map <F12> :lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>
inoremap <F12> <C-o>:lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>

" code completion with omni function
inoremap <C-Space> <C-x><C-o>
inoremap <C-@> <C-x><C-o>
```

`config.lua`

```lua
-- LSP config
local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
local servers = { 'bashls', 'sumneko_lua', 'solargraph', 'tsserver', 'vimls' }
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup({})
end
```

Full config files:

- https://github.com/paulodiovani/dot-files/blob/1f4166898a839a630e5aa7fd3bbd50fffc855609/home/user/.config/nvim/init.vim#L15-L17
- https://github.com/paulodiovani/dot-files/blob/1f4166898a839a630e5aa7fd3bbd50fffc855609/home/user/.config/nvim/init.vim#L34-L44
- https://github.com/paulodiovani/dot-files/blob/1f4166898a839a630e5aa7fd3bbd50fffc855609/home/user/.config/nvim/lua/config.lua#L54-L59

Output of `:LspInfo`

```
 Language client log: /home/diovani/.cache/nvim/lsp.log
 Detected filetype:   javascript
 
 2 client(s) attached to this buffer: 
 
 Client: tsserver (id: 1, pid: 114182, bufnr: [1])
    filetypes:       javascript, javascriptreact, javascript.jsx, typescript, typescriptreact, typescript.tsx
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  /home/diovani/Development/Node/interactive-pbta-bot
    cmd:             typescript-language-server --stdio
 
 Client: null-ls (id: 2, pid: 5001, bufnr: [1])
    filetypes:       typescriptreact, typescript, javascriptreact, javascript, vue, lua, ruby, sh, less, scss, sass, css, yaml, json
    autostart:       false
    root directory:  /home/diovani/Development/Node/interactive-pbta-bot
    cmd:             nvim
 
 Configured servers list: bashls, sumneko_lua, solargraph, tsserver, vimls
```

Comment: Given that there's a `tsserver` in there, it may only be getting set up for typescript files. Also, consider that a JS LSP can only do so much (like imported functions) because of all the dynamic "stuff"

Comment: [update] I included the output of `:LspInfo`

Comment: What is weird is that it is not correctly showing completions even for some native classes. `Object` and `Array` does not work. `Math` does. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/rs47cx/tsserver_and_vimlspomnifunc/.

Neovim comes with its built-in javascript autocomplete which was overriding the `omnifunc`.

To check if that is happening, open a Javascript file and type:

```
set omnifunc?
```

if the result is `omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS` it is using the built-in autocomplete.

The solution is to set `omnifunc` (and keymaps, if any) on the attach event of the LSP servers setup, as [suggested in `lsp_config` docs](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/c06c37b61c06d4e1574c014dfa3c3af8536e45ec/README.md#suggested-configuration).

> Note: you must pass the defined on_attach as an argument to every setup {} call and the keybindings in on_attach only take effect on buffers with an active language server.

Here is my final configuration, finally working:

```lua
-- LSP config
local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
local servers = { 'bashls', 'sumneko_lua', 'solargraph', 'tsserver', 'vimls' }
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup({
    on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
      vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')
      vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'tagfunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.tagfunc')
    end
  })
end
```

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how LSP works with a non typed language.